# How to redirect Parallel::ForkManager and Exec's STDOUT to file

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, fork

I am trying to run multiple commands using Perl Parallel:ForkManager. I want these commands to run at different time period. I am using an subroutine is_time_elapsed to check is it time to run the command. If the subroutine returns 0, then i am running the command using parallel fork manager. Command is getting executed but i am seeing the the STDOUT in the screen. Rather i want to redirect STDOUT and STDERR in to a file.How can i prevent the STDOUT from seeing in the screen and redirected to file

My requirement is to run the commands in background after the time is elapsed . I need to log the execution time when the command completed executing.This script will be a master script which will run infinitely and run the commands when the time is elapsed. Is there any other modules to achieve this other than Parallel::ForkManager.

```
my $forkMgr = Parallel::ForkManager->new(15);
$forkMgr->run_on_finish(
    sub {
        ($pid, $exitCode, $ident) = @_;
        print "Ended ==> $ident\n";
    }
);

while (1) {
    foreach my $cmd (@commands) {
        if (is_time_elapsed($cmd)) {
            $forkMgr->start($cmd)
               and next;
            exec("$cmd")
               or die("exec: $!");
            $forkMgr->finish;
        }
    }
    sleep 30
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're rolling your own `crond`. Anyway, do you need the STDOUT in the program at all? You can overwrite it permanently, or you could capture it.

Comment: Not Exactly but Similar to cron :). I am ok without STDOUT, only I need STDERR in case of any issues in the Commands executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To redirect all output from the whole program and its children:

```
main_program >log 2>&1
```

---

To only redirect the output of the children:

```
if (is_time_elapsed($cmd)) {
    $forkMgr->start($cmd)
       and next;
    open(STDOUT, '>>', 'log')
       or die("open: $!");
    open(STDERR, '>>&', \*STDOUT)
       or die("open: $!");
    exec("$cmd")
       or die("exec: $!");
}
```

You could even redirect the output of each child to a different file if you so desired.

---

Note: I got rid of the `$forkMgr->finish`. It was never reached (and that's fine).

Answer (score 2):

As usual in Perl, there are a couple of ways you can achieve this. You haven't said what exact output you want to send to files, or if you need the real `STDOUT` at all. Let's explore your options.

### You never need `STDOUT` anywhere in your program

If your main program as well as all the workers never should print anything to `STDOUT`, you could just run it with an output redirection. That enables you to do debugging on `STDOUT` during development, and to write to a file in production.

Simply start your program with `>output.log` attached to the command. The output of all forks will also go to the file. `STDERR` will remain intact.

```
$ perl forker.pl >output.log
```

This should be the preferred way if you want all output to go to a file.

Alternatively, you can implement this in Perl. That would make you lose the ability to debug on the console, and you would always have to look at the file. Use [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) to change `print`'s default handle. Be sure to use append-mode `>>` for the new handle.

```
open my $fh, '>>', 'output.log' or die $!;
select $fh;

my $forkMgr = Parallel::FormManager->new(15);
# ...
```

Now all output will also go to the file. [See this blog post](http://perltricks.com/article/45/2013/10/27/How-to-redirect-and-restore-STDOUT/) for more info on how this works, and how to restore the original `STDOUT`.

### Catpure `STDOUT`

[Capture::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Catpure::Tiny) is great to grab the `STDOUT` of things. You could use that to wrap the `exec`.

```
use Capture::Tiny 'capture_stdout';

# ...

my $stdout = capture_stdout {
    exec($cmd);
}
```

Now you can write it to a file.

### Use a logger

[Log::Log4Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl) is the go-to module for advanced logging. You should be able to tell it to not only grab everything from `STDERR`, but also from `STDOUT`. I've not researched this, but it should work.

Comment: That `select` approach won't work. The child has no idea of the internals of its Perl parent.

Comment: None of the solutions redirect STDERR!

Comment: @ikegami that is the point. OP said that in a comment. They want to write STDOUT to a file, and keep STDERR.

Comment: They said the main program needs STDERR unredirected (in that comment), but they also said the children needs STDERR redirected (in the question).